# mongoDB $match aggregation returns empty array when there is no query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework, aggregation

i am using $match in aggregation pipeline. When I don't pass the query in $match it prints empty array. But I want all data when there is empty query in $match. same time if query is not match then it should print empty array. how to do this?.

```
export const getMovies = async (req, res) => {
const actorname = req.query.name
const genrename = req.query.genre
const movies = await Movie.aggregate(
    [
        { $addFields: { genre: '$genres' } },
        { $match: { name: actorname } },
        { $unwind: "$genre" },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$genre',
                movieCount: { $sum: 1 },
                movies: {
                    $push:
                    {
                        movie: "$movie",
                        genre: "$genres",
                        name: "$name",
                        rating: "$rating"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        { $addFields: { genre: '$_id' } },
        { $project: { _id: 0 } },
        { $match: { genre: genrename } }
    ]
)
res.status(200).json({ movies })}
```

Comment: Would you show the code where you execute your aggregation pipeline and also where _"it prints empty array"_?

Comment: @rickhg12hs please check it out. it prints empty if i dont pass query

Comment: When you _"don't pass the query"_, what are `actorname` and `genrename` values?

Comment: @rickhg12hs it prints undefined

Comment: I think you'll need some new logic.  If those values are undefined, I believe `$match` will search for `null` values.  If there are no `null` values, then nothing will pass the `$match`.

Comment: Could you please share the logic?

Comment: One approach might be to recognize that the aggregation pipeline is an array of objects.  The objects in the array could be added, or not, based on some condition - here, whether a variable is defined, or not.

Answer (score 0):

this shouldn't be happening, Can you please share the code where you execute the aggregation. If you check the image attached, an empty $match stage just matches against nothing, or no query. Its like doing an empty find operation, it will return everything.[image]

Comment: if i don't pass query via postman it returns empty array.